# Is there any way to send multipart form request to graphql in reactjs with react relay modern

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

I am new to react with graphql.

I want to upload all type file to server via network interface.

All I need to do is write a graphql mutation using relay which sends multipart form data to server.

I tried to search it on google but I did't found any proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only real standard transport for GraphQL messages is [a JSON HTTP POST](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request).  "File upload" isn't a concept at all in GraphQL; you'd have to encode your file contents in JSON (probably base64 encoding it first) and pass it as a parameter to a mutation, probably in the `"variables":` block.

```
{
  "query": "mutation Upload($name: String!, $contents: String!) { uploadFile(name: $name, contents: $contents) { id } }",
  "variables": {
    "name": "hello.txt",
    "contents": "aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ="
  }
}
```

Another path you might consider is to generate single-use upload URLs.  Then you'd have a GraphQL mutation that initiated the upload and returned the URL

```graphql
mutation StartUpload($name: String) {
  startUpload(name: $name) {
    id
    url
  }
}
```

and then your application can HTTP POST the file to the returned URL.  Implementing this is left as an exercise.